# How do landers communicate with Earth when facing away?

Tags: communication, lander, deep-space-network

For example, how do the Mars landers communicate when Mars is between them and the Earth? The MRO is in a low orbit; does it store and forward data?

Comment: Consider https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/how-do-non-earth-facing-vehicles-communicate-with-earth?rq=1 
Specifically, why could your vehicle not aim its receptors one way and its transceivers another?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In this question, it’s not a matter of antenna steering. There is a planet in the way.

Comment: Are you restricting this to today's landers, boldy landing where no landers have landed before, or including tomorrow's craft, which should be able to use, for instance relatively cheap and simple satellite relay chains?

If it's only about today's landers, isn't the intervening planet so much of a nuisance that it negates the Question?

In between falls Antzi's idea, below, of a satellite overhead.

Can you clarify the time-frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't.

If a satellite is overhead, it can be used to store the data and replay it to earth, but otherwise the channel is broken.

You can find more details if you look at Schiaparelli landing, most articles explained this issue altho I don't have one right now at hand.

Comment: Can you run that back, please?

Is the point how data might be sent back to Earth, or what?

Either way, what might "the channel is broken" mean, other than that line-of-sight was the only method you saw as workable?

Who doubts that any satellite can be used to store data?

Is the point how that data might be sent back to Earth, or what?

Either way, what might "the channel is broken" mean, other than that straight line-of-sight was the only workable method…which who could ever doubt?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes my point was that line of sight is required for communications, which is what OP was asking about.