# How do satellites ensure they are orientated towards the Earth to allow of clear connections?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, attitude, communication-satellite

As the title says,

How do satellites ensure they are orientated towards the Earth to allow of clear connections, whilst having their solar panels face the sun?

I understand reaction wheels are involved, but I'm unsure of the specifics.

Comment: There are lots of ways.  From what I understand a Gravity Boom is the most common:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity-gradient_stabilization

Comment: I would say that this is answered here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/does-a-satellite-naturally-turn-in-phase-with-its-orbit-always-facing-earth " want a satellite to constantly point its radio dish towards Earth while orbiting it, or its solar panels towards the Sun if it is instead orbiting it. "